# getting SSL error on GeddyJs using Heroku PG on dev environment

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, geddy

i am using GeddyJs with a heroku cedar app deployment. I am using Heroku Postgres services for the database.

I have configured the username/password/hostname/dbname in the config file on geddyjs but when i go to run `node app.js` it throws an error for no `pg_hba.conf` i know this related to SSL not being used while accessing the db remotely but i have no clue how to force SSL on the connection..

## Here is the error log:

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "70.199.196.17", user "12345", database "database1", SSL off
    at p.parseE (/Users/mikedevita/Web/Sites/gorelative.com/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:503:11)
    at p.parseMessage (/Users/mikedevita/Web/Sites/gorelative.com/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:363:17)
    at Socket.p.attachListeners (/Users/mikedevita/Web/Sites/gorelative.com/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:86:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:397:14)
[Tue, 05 Mar 2013 22:39:49 GMT] ERROR Worker 843 died.
```

## my config/development.js file:

```
var config = {
  detailedErrors: true
, debug: true
, hostname: 'localhost'
, port: 3000
, model: {
    defaultAdapter: 'postgres'
  }
, db: {
    postgres: {
        port: 5432
      , password: 'foobar' 
      , database: 'database1'
      , host: 'ec2-107-21-126-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
      , user: '12345'
    }
  }
, sessions: {
    store: 'memory'
  , key: 'sid'
  , expiry: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ssl: true` to your postgres config.

```
postgres: {
    port: 5432
  , password: 'foobar' 
  , database: 'database1'
  , host: 'ec2-107-21-126-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
  , user: '12345'
  , ssl: true
}
```

Geddy simply passes this config object to the pg module. Check the [pg.client wiki page](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#constructor) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to connect from outside heroku you need to connect with SSL. We only allow connections from outside heroku if they are encrypted with SSL

`error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "70.199.196.17", user "12345", database "database1", SSL off` says that you can't connect with SSL off.

Also you may be sanitizing your database name with database1, but if you're not, I can guarantee you that your database name is not, in fact, database1.

Also you should **NOT NOT NOT** be hard-coding your credentials in a file. Read them out of your environment.

Comment: Thanks, This is for development as i dont have pg installed locally. my credentials are stored in my env like you recommend already. Also i changed my db name/user/pass info for the purpose of the question